# Validate Email Address with MailGun API

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm able to use the mailgun api to send email, but when I try to validate an email address then I get a 403 error (which comes through as `An HTTP Error has occurred! Check your network connection and try again.` which is a bad error message).

I've tried using both the public and private api keys along with the public and private email validation endpoints. Neither work, both give me a 403.

```
$mg = Mailgun::create($private_apikey);
$validation = $mg->get('address/private/validate', array('address' => $email));

$mg = Mailgun::create($public_apikey);
$validation = $mg->get('address/validate', array('address' => $email));
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

to prevent abuse, we require a credit card on the account to make use of the email validations feature. You will not be charged - all free accounts include 10,000 messages and 100 email validations.

Once you apply a credit card to your account you should be all set!

Mike || Mailgun Sales Engineer

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem: a 403 with both the private and public key. I do have a credit card on my account. Could there be any other reason for this failing? When I use the curl method, the system responds with "Validations are not enabled".